Problem with Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core Middleware - Continuous Redirect to Login
I'm having an issue with middleware configuration in my ASP.NET Core application that runs on IIS with Windows Authentication enabled. My application uses proxy middleware to forward requests to another server. However, when I try to access the /ecp path, the application continuously redirects me to the login page.
Here’s the code for my middleware:
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ECP.Web.Configurations.Middleware
{


public static class Routing
{
    public static void Apply(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseMiddleware<SimpleProxyMiddleware>();


        // Routing dla CommonController
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "ecpRoute",
            pattern: "ecp/{action=Index}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "Index" });  


        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Common}/{action=Index}");

        app.MapRazorPages();
    }
}



    public class SimpleProxyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILogger<SimpleProxyMiddleware> _logger;

        public SimpleProxyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<SimpleProxyMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,  // This setting passes Windows Authentication credentials
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            };

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var upstreamPath = context.Request.Path.Value;

            // Check if the request has already been processed by this middleware
            if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Proxy-Processed"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Request already processed by proxy, passing to next middleware.");
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            if (upstreamPath.StartsWith("/ecp"))
            {
                // Modify the URL to point to the downstream service
                var downstreamUrl = $"https://ecp.dev.ad.ulcp:44392{upstreamPath}";

                _logger.LogInformation("Requesting URL: {DownstreamUrl}", downstreamUrl);

                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = new HttpMethod(context.Request.Method),
                    RequestUri = new Uri(downstreamUrl)
                };

                // Mark the request as processed by this proxy
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Proxy-Processed", "true");

                // Copy request headers, including authentication information
                _logger.LogInformation("Request Headers:");
                foreach (var header in context.Request.Headers)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("{HeaderKey}: {HeaderValue}", header.Key, string.Join(", ", header.Value));
                    requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray());
                }

                try
                {
                    // Send the request to the downstream service
                    var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode;

                    _logger.LogInformation("Response Status Code: {StatusCode}", responseMessage.StatusCode);

                    // Copy response headers
                    _logger.LogInformation("Response Headers:");
                    foreach (var header in responseMessage.Headers)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("{HeaderKey}: {HeaderValue}", header.Key, string.Join(", ", header.Value));
                        context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
                    }

                    foreach (var header in responseMessage.Content.Headers)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("{HeaderKey}: {HeaderValue}", header.Key, string.Join(", ", header.Value));
                        context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
                    }

                    context.Response.Headers.Remove("transfer-encoding");

                    // Forward the response content
                    await responseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the request.");
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
}


Issue:

When: I'm using this middleware in an application hosted on IIS.

What happens: When I try to access the /ecp path, the application continuously redirects me to the login page.

What I’ve tried: I ensured that UseDefaultCredentials is set to true to pass Windows credentials to the downstream server. I also checked the headers being passed, but I can't seem to figure out what might be wrong.


IIS Configuration:

Windows Authentication is enabled.
Forms Authentication is disabled.

Ocelot Configuration:
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ecp/{url}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "ecp.dev.ad.uclp", 
      "Port": 443
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/ecp/{url}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
}


Question:
How can I properly pass the user’s credentials using Windows Authentication in this proxy middleware? Any suggestions on what might be causing the continuous redirect to the login page?
Thanks for any help!


Please follow the steps to add DisableStrictNameChecking and BackConnectionHostNames in Registry Editor.
And Run Command Prompt as Administrator.
net stop iisadmin /y
net start iisadmin

Then it should be work. Here is my test result.

